# Контейнер без выхода в интернет

Tags: docker, docker-compose

У меня есть файл docker-compose

```
    version: '2'
services:
  first:
    image: alpine
    entrypoint: "ping 8.8.8.8"
  second:
    image: alpine
    entrypoint: "ping first"
```

Нужно сделать так что бы второй контейнер не имел доступа к интернету, но мог пинговаться с первым контейнером. Если задать

> network_mode: none

второй контейнер отсоединиться от дефолтной сети и не будет видит первый контейнер

Comment: Ну наверно нужно делать маршрутизацию между контейнерами. Проброс портов и линковку. Один будет в интернете другой в локале, а между ними пробросить маршрут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно объявить две сети: изолированную и обычную:

```
networks:
    isolated:
        internal: true
    net:
        driver: bridge
```

Чтобы контейнеры видели друг друга, добавляем оба в сеть `isolated`, а тот, которому нужен интернет, добавляем в сеть `net`:

```
services:
  first:
    image: alpine
    entrypoint: "ping 8.8.8.8"
    networks:
     - net
     - isolated
  second:
    image: alpine
    entrypoint: "ping first"
    networks:
     - isolated
```